# How to migrate MySQL databases to my local machine

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, mysql

I have two exactly same mysql databases with different data running on Amazon AWS.  I would like to move those databases to my local machine.  They are not too big databases less than 1GB. I read about mysqldump but it is too complicated and could not find easy follow on instructions.

First, tried using MySQL workbench migration tool and cant connect to the source.

Second, I tried connecting to the databases from the workbench but failed.

Third, I tried to move table by table, but when I export it to .csv file and try to open it table formation is lost.

How can I move combine those databases and move to my local computer efficiently?

Comment: `mysqldump` is the least complicated way to do this, so any other answer will probably be worse.

Comment: there is an option in phpmyadmin for that

Comment: @DanFromGermany `mysql | cat export.sql`? Are you sure?

Comment: @MattGibson Ah.. `cat export.sql | mysql` or `mysql < export.sql` should work.

Comment: @DanFromGermany introducing [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your ssh shell (terminal)

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > exported.sql
```

now move the dump to the target system (your local computer) and do

```
mysql -u root -p < exported.sql
```

do this for each db-source and your done

PS: replace root if needed for DB admin username

**UPDATE**:
You can do this on the fly from source to destination in one line:

```
mysqldump -h source_hostname_or_ip -u root --password='password' --extended-insert --databases DatabaseName | mysql -u root --password='password' --host=destination_host -C DatabaseName
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not able to connect using Workbench? Fill in your SSH IP(port(22) not needed), Select the SSH Key file(In text format & not ppk), Fill in your RDS instance End Point and credentials.

Then TEST CONNECTION...

If successful, you can use EXPORT option, select your DB and proceed!